# Inheriting from Panel - where should I remove handler?

Tags: vb.net

I have a code like this....

```
Public Class MyWebBrowser
    Inherits Panel

    Private _browser As WebBrowser


    Public Sub New()
        _browser = New WebBrowser
        AddHandler _browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf DocumentCompleted
    End Sub


    Private Sub DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
        ' Do stuff.
    End Sub


    Private Sub MyWebBrowser_Disposed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Disposed
        RemoveHandler _browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf DocumentCompleted
        ' Fails ... _browser is nothing - where shoud I remove the handler?
    End Sub

End Class
```

But I can't figure out where to remove the handler? I can't see a "Disposing" event of the panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I can't figure out where to remove the handler? I can't see a "Disposing" event of the panel.

IMHO you should declare `_browser` as `WithEvents`, let the framework handle adding and removing the event handlers. For example:

```
Public Class MyWebBrowser : Inherits Panel

    Private WithEvents _browser As WebBrowser

    Public Sub New()
        _browser = New WebBrowser
    End Sub

    Private Sub _browser_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles _browser.DocumentCompleted
        'Do stuff
    End Sub

End Class
```

Please note the important part of this is `Handles _browser.DocumentCompleted`, the framework will handle disposing these for you.

On another note, *if you really want to handle disposing* (you don't want to and no need to), you need to `Override` it:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
   If disposing Then
      _browser.Dispose()
   End If
   MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
End Sub
```

Please [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/withevents) more there about `WithEvents` and how it works.

Comment: This is correct. In C#, you'd have to worry about IDisposable stuff, but VB.Net makes working with events just a little easier.